# multiple .htaccess files conflicting with each other

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a shared hosting with multiple domain hosted on it. In the root folder of my hosting exists a .htaccess (say is htaccess1). Code in ht1 is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mydomain/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mydomain/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ mydomain/index.php [L]
```

These rules are there so that only urls with `www.mydomain.com` use all files of `mydomain` folder. I am new to url rewriting so I don't understand the meaning of what each line does. Another .htaccess (say htaccess2) file exists in `mydomain` folder. Code is htaccess2 is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)?/$ try.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)?$ try.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)?/$ post.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)?$ post.php?id=$1
```

In this file, line 6,7 works fine and redirect requests with numeric parameters to `try.php` but lines 8,9 doesn't work and gives a 404 page not found error, exact error string is :

> The requested URL /mydomain/post/1233445 was not found on this server.

I doubt that some effect of htaccess1 is creating this problem as I tried many variations of regex in line 8,9. Please help.

Comment: `RewriteCond` works in order up to the first `RewriteRule` unless you're using something like skip to skip over a failed match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mydomain/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mydomain/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /mydomain/index.php [L]
```

**Changes:**

1. Added RewriteBase at the top.
2. Added `L` flag to mark it last rule.
3. Added required options.

mydomain .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mydomain/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)/?$ post.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ try.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**Changes:**

1. Added RewriteBase at the top.
2. Added L flag to mark it last rule.
3. Removed a redundant rule.
4. Moved specific rule above the generic rule.
5. Added required options.

Comment: can u plz elaborate a bit about what changes have u made?

Comment: @Sourabh: I will sure do that but I suggest you try out these changes once and tell me it works or not and I will provide a brief explanation accordingly.

Comment: No it doesn't. Also, when I removed last 2 lines of base htaccess, it started giving a 403 forbidden request error.

Comment: Yes I checked. Still it doesn't work. Am not sure if the rewrite base thing is in effect. Still giving same error.

Comment: Ok what URI did you try? If you want you can comment out RewriteBase line as well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29208/discussion-between-anubhava-and-sourabh)